# Linear Algebra; Properties of bijective compositions and linearity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

If $f:E \rightarrow E$ is a linear map and $f^3$ is bijective, then is $f$ bijective?
  Would the result be true if $f$ is not linear?
  I would like to explore for the linear and the non-linear case.

**This is what I have:**

$f^3$ is bijective and $f$ is linear.

So, $\exists ! x \in E$ s.t. $f(x)=y$ for $! y \in E$.  Similarly, for $f(y)$, $\exists !z \in E$ s.t. $f(y)=z$.

Similarly, for $f(z),$ $\exists ! a \in E$ s.t. $f(z)=a$.

So, $f(f(f(x)))= f(f(y))=f(z)=a$.

And since $f(x)=y$ is bijective, $i$) and $ii$) follow:

$i$) $f^2$ is bijective ($f(f(x))=f(y)$ for $y \in E$, bijectively mapped by $f(x) for x\in E$.

$ii$) $f(f(f(x)))=f(f(z))$ (similarly)

Concluding that $f^3$ is bijective.

This convinces me that this is true whether $f$ is linear or not, because I didn't even use the fact that the function was linear in the proof. Is this correct? Feedback? Corrections?

Comment: Since $f^3$ is bijective, it is, in particular, injective, so
$$
f^{3}(x) \neq 0
$$
implies
$$
f(x) \neq 0,
$$
i.e., $f$ is injective.

Comment: there is no need for $f$ to be linear

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f^3$ iso $\Rightarrow \exists g$ such that $f^3\circ g = f\circ (f^2\circ g)= id$ and $g^{-1}\circ f^3 = (g^{-1}\circ f^2)\circ f = id$.

Answer (score 0):

A. $f^3$ is injective.
  So, $Kern (f^3) = \{0\}$.

$\iff f^2(0) = 0$, $\iff f(0) = 0$ and thus, $f$ is injective.

B. $\forall e \in E$, $\exists x \in E$ s.t. $f^3(x)=e$.

Since $e = f^3(x)=f(f^2(x))$, there must exist $f^2(x) \in E$ that maps to any $e \in E$, and thus, $f$ is surjective.